# How to run a jquery function but only when the browser window width is > 1024px?

Tags: media-queries, jquery, browser-width

This is a functionality I'd like to add to my responsive one-page website, but only when the browser width is greater than 1024px.

My knowledge of jQuery is minimal. This is the code I have now:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var pageWidth = $(window).width();
        if (pageWidth > 1024) {

$('.footer a').mouseenter(function() {
$(this).effect("bounce", { times:1, distance:4 }, 250);
});

});
});
```

This is the code I have in the HTML that loads this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tiny-bounce.js"></script>
```

Another question, when this function isn't firing—for example when a user loads the site on a device that has < 1024px width, do they still have to load the javascript file?

Comment: please be clear in your question you have asked for <1024px is your question correct??

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do this is

instead of this

```
if (pageWidth > 1024) {
```

do this

```
if (pageWidth < 1024) {
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch this error in my question, but someone pointed it out and I fixed it.
I've uploaded the latest site files. Maybe you can check it out for yourself--it's still giving an error--http://vitaliyg.com

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you still have to load the JS code when the width is less than 1024, unless you include this code in your HTML or an existing JS script.

I believe you can call `$(window).width()` without `$(document).ready()`, so that could be one way to lessen the impact of having this extra code on small screens.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I already have analytics code in my html file--can I place this code under it?